# Simplifing if statement?

Tags: logic

Is it possible to simplify this if statement?

and if so what's the answer?

```
    if (type)
    {
        if(NdotL >= 0.0)
        {
            color   += Idiff + Ispec;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        color   += Idiff + Ispec;
    }
```

Comment: There are four possible states, and only one of them results in the statement *not* being executed...

Answer (score 6):

Think about this in terms of Boolean algebra. You have two conditions

```
A = (type)
B = (NdotL >= 0.0 )
```

And you execute your statement when

```
A * B
/A
```

( I use `/A` to indicate "NOT A", and `*` to indicate "AND" )

So the only time you don't execute is

```
A * /B
```

This means your statement should be

```
if (!((type) && NdotL < 0.0 )) {
  // do your thing
}
```

Or, using Boolean identity

```
(A * B) = /(/A + /B)
```

you can rewrite your condition as

```
( /A + B )

if ( !(type) || ( NdotL >= 0 ) ) {
   // do your thing
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
if (!type || NdotL >= 0.0)
{
    color += Idiff + Ispec;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if (type && NdotL > 0.0){
   Blah....
} else {
   Buegh...
}
```

Just so that it combines the two conditions.

Really sorry about indentations and such, but the mobile version of this site doesn't let you enter code, I just wanted to help you so much XD!

Comment: What I4r3nZu wrote is probably a lot simpler in terms of number of lines of code. This way should be easier to read, but if you are going for elegance what he said is good!

Comment: Fixed indents for you. You can actually just type a newline followed by four spaces to enter each line of code when on the mobile site - I do it frequently. And I think you meant `>=` not `>`. I will blame it on the mobile site...

Answer (score 0):

Try that :

```
color+=(type && NdotL >= 0.0)? Idiff + Ispec:Idiff + Ispec;
```

Comment: The key here is *simplifying*. Besides, that's completely null. Both of your return values are the same.

Comment: Not introducing bugs would also be nice.

Comment: Lol I thought this might catch a few people out, it's been a long night and my brain couldn't wrap around this simple problem we've all been there.